# Converting a .m3u playlist with Sed

Tags: regex, batch-file, sed

I am writing a Batch script that is using Sed (Version 4.2.1 by gnuwin32) to convert a .m3u playlist (generated with Windows Media Player) and bring it over into a format that is accepted as an input for the TeamSpeak 3 plugin "Soundboard" (from http://www.kampfrausch.de/ts3).

The general idea is to perform 8 sets of search and replace all:

- 1)
  search :
  \.\.\\\.\.\\
  replace:
  C:\\Users\\Me\\
- 2)
  search:
  \.\.\\
  replace:
  C:\\Users\\Me\\Music\\
- 3)
  search:
  #EXTM3U
  replace:
  EMPTY_STRING_HERE
- 4)
  search:
  :0,
  replace:
  :-1,
- 5)
  search:
  \\
  replace:
  /
- 6)
  search:
  C:/
  replace:
  file:///C:/
- 7)
  search:
  .mp3\r\nfile
  replace:
  \r\nfile
- 8)
  search:
  ^\r\n
  replace:
  EMPTY_STRING_HERE

Manually performed (with Notepad++ Find and Replace) this already works and the playlist is completely functional.

However, I seem not to be able to write a syntax for 7) and 8) in Sed, since Sed is not the best tool for comparing multiple lines at a time.

Here is the code so far:

```
@echo off

sed s/\.\.\\\.\.\\/C:\\Users\\Me\\/g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

sed s/\.\.\\/C:\\Users\\Me\\Music\\/g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

sed s/#EXTM3U//g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

sed s/:0,/:-1,/g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

sed s/\\/\//g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

sed s/C:\//file:\/\/\/C:\//g badplaylist.m3u > temp.dat
type temp.dat > badplaylist.m3u

:: 7) expression, that removes ".mp3" at the end of a line if the NEXT line starts with "file:///C:/"

:: 8) remove all completely empty lines

del temp.dat
```

Does someone have an idea how I can solve 7) and 8)?

Of course I don't need a Sed code, it just was a nice option so far. All I need is a solution that works in Batch.

Greeting, Joe

Comment: #8 is easy, just `sed '/^$/d'`.  For 7, maybe there's something useful [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt).  Your code comment for 7 doesn't quite match #7 in your bullet list.  Do you want `.mp3` replaced, or `\r\nfile` replaced?

Comment: That's right, but if the next line starts with "file..." it automatically starts with an f and there is no other term with f that could be at the beginning of a line in my case. Changed it due to clarity though, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not a regexp expert at all, I wrote a Batch-JScript hybrid script called FindRepl.bat that provides the user with the same regexp capabilities of MS JScript language, so it run in any Windows versions from XP on. The interesting point of my program is that it allows you to perform *several* replacements in the same run, as long as they does not depends on each other. You may also define the sets of replacements in a text file instead of a very long command line. This way, your replacement set may be defined in a file called M3UtoSoundboard.txt, for example, with this contents:

```
// Replacements file to convert an .m3u playlist into a Soundboard compatible one
// Use this file with FindRepl.bat program
// http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697

// 1) search : \.\.\\\.\.\\ replace: C:\\Users\\Me\\
\.\.\\\.\.\\||'C:\\Users\\Me\\'

// 2) search: \.\.\\ replace: C:\\Users\\Me\\Music\\
\.\.\\||'C:\\Users\\Me\\Music\\'

// 3) search: #EXTM3U replace: EMPTY_STRING_HERE
#EXTM3U||''

// 4) search: :0, replace: :-1,
:0,||':-1,'

// 5) search: \\ replace: /
\\||'\/'

// 6) search: C:/ replace: file:///C:/
C:\/||'file:\/\/\/C:\/'

// 7) search: .mp3\r\nfile replace: \r\nfile
\.mp3\r\nfile||'\r\nfile'

// 8) search: ^\r\n replace: EMPTY_STRING_HERE
^\r\n||''
```

Each line have a regexp and its replacement value separated by `||`; however, the replacement is *not* a string, but a JScript expression, so it may include any function or method (like `.toUpperCase()`, etc.). For this reason, when the replacement is a literal string it must be enclosed in apostrophes.

You may download FindRepl.bat program from [this site](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697); a full documentation is included at that site below the source code. After that, execute it this way:

```
< thePlaylist.m3u FindRepl /G:M3UtoSoundboard.txt /A /J > theConvertedList.xyz
```

I'll appreciate it if you may report the result you get if you use this program.

Comment: Rested for a few days on this problem, but here is my result: Your version worked quite well, but I am still trying to find a Batch(-only) solution (with no dependance on JScript). For an end user your tool is perfectly fine, but it doesn't quite fill the requirements that I made for myself. Also I would feel kinda bad if I just copied your code :P

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Did my program created working Soundboard-compatible playlists using the replacements file above? Didn't you need to adjust it in any way? Could you add any other comment, like how fast it is?. Thanks again... **`:-)`**

Comment: For speed we're talking about a time far below a second. All I did was using your syntax and my search&replace expressions to get your script working, thank you. Since I am low on time I will probably release a JScript-free version in the next days and post it as an answer.

Comment: Excuse me. The important point for me now is to test the multiple replacements in one run feature of my program, via two long _alternations_ or via a replacements file (like the one I posted). Did you run my program _8 times_ to get your result? If so, I'll appreciate it if you may test the file method (or the _alternations_ method) and report the result. TIA!